# How does -XX:+UseNUMA affects JVM performance for systems with only one node?

Tags: java, performance, jvm, numa

There is a numerous articles regarding benefits of JVM NUMA-aware allocators.  However I could not find information about what performance impact may cause [`-XX:+UseNUMA`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#numa) flag for single-node topologies like

```
# numactl --hardware
available: 1 nodes (0)
node 0 cpus: 0 1 2 3
node 0 size: 32060 MB
node 0 free: 7770 MB
node distances:
node   0 
  0:  10
```

It seems that this is a kind of corner case and there is no real profit in enabling flag. If so is there any drawbacks may be caused by enabling it?

Comment: So the question is, does it hurt to `+UseNUMA` on hardware which happens to be UMA? I think there will be very few people who can authoritatively answer that.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yep. I realize that this question will not gain quick response :/ I tried to make a couple of benchmarks to see if there is a difference but still no luck with answer.

Comment: Any potential answer is of course highly sensitive to each specific architecture and JVM version/variant.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Theoretical answer will be ok :) It seems to me that jvm could do nothing with just one node but on the other side it will be interesting how does allocator deals with it.

Comment: Theoretically, within the node you could have non-uniform distances between cores. This is probably already true with today's core counts. Subsets of cores share an L2 cache, for example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`-XX:+UseNUMA` does no harm in these cases.
HotSpot JVM automatically turns off the flag when run on a single node [(the source)](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/2198ef7e1c17/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp#l4931).

Comment: that's only Java 11 onwards.https://dzone.com/articles/openjdk-updates-usenuma-with-more-robust-membind-f